# friendly_id, Delete slug from history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, friendly-id

I am using `friendly_id` with the `history` module for a model called `page` and would like to be able to delete slugs from the `friendly_id_slugs` table so that they no longer redirect and can be used again.

I have come up with a couple of possible solutions, but am unsure of how to proceed:

1. Create a new model and controller for the `friendly_id_table` and do things as I would for any other model
2. Add a `destroy_slug` action to `pages_controller.rb` that looks up the slug and destroys it - however, I'm unsure of how to load the slug, maybe `FriendlyId::Slug.find()`
3. Create a controller in the `FriendlyId` namespace - no idea how to do this

Can anyone make a suggestion as the best way to proceed or how to accomplish #2 or #3?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently am implementing this as like so:

```
# slug_controller.rb
class SlugsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @slug = FriendlyId::Slug.find(params[:id])
    @slug.destroy
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "The URL <strong>/#{@slug.slug}</strong> has been removed"
  end
end

# routes.rb
resources :slugs, :only => :destroy

# in a view
<%= link_to 'Delete slug', slug_path(slug.id), :method => :delete %>
```